# I cannot understand the behavior of scrollRectToVisible:animated: with scrollView.contentInset set

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

When `scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero`, everything is just OK, so the problem I run into arises when `scrollView.contentInset` is set manually.

In order to describe the problem, I'll make a simple demo.

Drag a scroll view (also make a reference to it, and set its background color to be different from white, say **red**) onto the scene, then drag a view onto the scroll view (don't forget to set its background color, say **green**), they are the same size and completely overlap. The document outline is as below:

[image]

Then some code:

```
let top: CGFloat = 100
let bottom: CGFloat = 50

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.bounds.width, 1000)
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, 0, bottom, 0)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.bounds.width, scrollView.bounds.height - bottom), animated: false) // this line will be change
}
```

The effect is as below, just as I expect:

[image]

But if I change the last line of code to be

```
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.bounds.width, scrollView.bounds.height - (bottom + 1)), animated: false)
```

The effect is like this:

[image]

I've changed only one point! What I expect is

[image]

How to explain this?

Comment: I can't explain the difference between the two, but both seem to actually work, albeit while making different choices as to where the "extra bits of content" are placed. You're aren't giving the scrollview a precise instruction there, just telling it to scroll a region of H-50 points (with H being the visible height) into view, and both screenshots show this (the first with the "extra bits" below, the second with the "extra bits" above).

Comment: @Clafou Thanks. Your analysis is right, there isn't enough information. Just because Xcode often puts the "extra bits of content" above, I'm inclined to think it should be always put above. Hope someone can distinguish the two circumstances.